# PHP Updating row in record to yes instead of no but it still shows even though code is for where X = no only

Tags: php, mysql, forms, loops, where-clause

The page is set to show all rows where isthisapproved equals no. This is working how I want by updating isthisapproved to yes. However, after updating isthisapproved from no to yes I don't want it to show anymore... but it is. I'm guessing I have some code in the wrong spot so it isn't "refreshing" the isthisapproved=no query.

```
 <form method='post'>";

 $query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE isthisapproved='no'";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<p>$count need approval</p>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 

$id=$row['id'];

echo "
<table>
 <tr> 
  <td>ID:</td>
  <td>$id <input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='$id'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <center><input name='submit' type='submit' value='Change To Yes'></form></center>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table><br>
";}

if($_POST['submit']) {
$update = "UPDATE table SET isthisapproved='yes' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
if(mysql_query($update)) $count++; 
else die("Error in query:<br>$sql<br>"); 

echo "<p><b>$name approval changed to yes</b></p>";
} 
?>
```

I'd also like to put the notice that the approval worked to be at the top of the page after an update is made instead of at the bottom. I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: Is this some kind of legacy application? I hope you're not using `mysql_query` in new code.

Comment: I have no idea what legacy application is.

Comment: Is this an old application that's been around for ages, full of code written years ago, or is it brand new code you're writing? What you're doing here is risky, you're not [properly escaping your SQL statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and are exposing yourself to [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). At the very least you should be using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Comment: It is based on code that was done quite a few years ago that I inherited. I know it isn't perfect or pretty but going off of the code I already have is how I've been "teaching" myself. Definitely not the best way and I will look into those links you provided.

Comment: If it's old, that's okay, but you will have to be very careful when using `mysql_query`. A guide like [PHP the Right Way](http://phptherightway.com/) serves as a reference for how it should probably be done and can help steer you in the right direction when overhauling old code.

Comment: Thank you for that guide. I am going to start reading that to help me get a better grasp on php/sql.

Answer (score 0):

The select query and the update query are using different column names.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE approved='no'";
                                  ^^^^^^^^  
$update = "UPDATE table SET isthisapproved='yes' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: In the actual code they are the same, I just changed them to something different for this example. Forgot to change the one in $query. Oops!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection consider using PDO..

Your id is an array so upon submit all of the ids will be sent to your script as it is all contained in one form.

You could wrap it in individual forms and there would also be no need for id to be an array... OR you could place a check box for each user and have the name as `id[]` then upon submit. you can do this...

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $v){
    //query goes here. $v is the ID
}
```

This could however be more efficient and generate a string to be sent as one query to update all users in one go.

Comment: I don't want to update them all at once. This code is being used to approve nominations after the appropriate information has been received. Once it is received that individual gets approved but the others do not.     My first attempt at this was with check boxes but I couldn't get it to work. I will try again with the code you provided.

Comment: I would really reconsider your layout then because that looks that what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh, move your update query to the top of the code, the reason being is it queries the database and fetches all the non approved and then updates the database you want it the other way around

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using "approved" column for select query and "isthisapproved" for update query. So anyway I am assuming it as a typo error. (If not then fix it).

Now pointing out some issue :

1. Correct your form starting tag and closing tag. Even though it is closing properly. So here form closing tag should be after finishing the table.
2. After submitting the form you are not receiving the id through $_POST. You are using direct $id which is wrong.

So here you should recieve the id like this and then pass it to update query :

$id = $_POST['id'];